# Existence of a Non-Invertible Matrix A + I with Given Norm Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $\| A \|_1 = \frac{\varphi + 1}{\varphi + 2}$ and $\| A \|_{\infty} = \frac{\varphi + 2}{\varphi + 3}$ where $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter. Additionally, let $I$ be the identity matrix of the same dimension.
Is there a matrix $A$ such that $A + I$ is not invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the norm of a matrix must be nonnegative, we must have $\varphi<-3$ or $\varphi\ge-1$.

When $\varphi\ge-1$, $A+I$ is always invertible, as $\rho(A)\le\|A\|_1<1$.

When $\varphi<-3$, $A+I$ may be singular. E.g. when $n=3$ and $\varphi=-4$, let
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ \frac12&-\frac12&0\\ 0&0&0},
\quad\text{so that}\quad
A+I=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ \frac12&\frac12&0\\ 0&0&1}
$$
is singular (because it has two identical columns), $\|A\|_1=\frac{3}{2}=\frac{\varphi+1}{\varphi+2}$ and $\|A\|_\infty=2=\frac{\varphi+2}{\varphi+3}$.